# D8 - Entity Load Cache

Tags: entities, caching

First of all. Are

```
$ent = Drupal\custom_entity\Entity\MyEntity::load(1);
```

and

```
 $ent = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('custom_entity')->load(1);
```

the same?

Also I know that 
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('custom_entity')->load()
is getting cached.

When I talk directly to the class's load function also?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all. Are ... and ... the same?

Assuming your entity type class doesn't override [`Entity::load`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Aload/8.5.x) to do something different, yes they are the same. If you look at that method you can see it uses exactly the same op:

```
public static function load($id) {
  $entity_type_repository = \Drupal::service('entity_type.repository');
  $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  $storage = $entity_type_manager
    ->getStorage($entity_type_repository
    ->getEntityTypeFromClass(get_called_class()));
  return $storage
    ->load($id);
}
```

So `Entity::load` is simply a shortcut to loading the entity via the manager service.

> When I talk directly to the class's load function also?

They're identical operations, so yes, they share the same caching.